# Como mantener una ejecución durante un periodo de tiempo

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un programa en el que necesito mantener una palabra durante 5 segundos por pantalla

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        escribir.setVisible(true);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Esto lo que hace que me pone la palabra justo cuando pasa los 5 segundos y yo lo que quiero es que al dar el botón salga la palabra y a los 5 segundos se quite.

Comment: Una alternative es usar un timer, supongo que estas usando swing te dejo una posible implementacion  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003044/how-to-stop-timer-in-a-swing-application

Comment: Simple, Cambia el orden.